# How can I Hide the first row for UniformGrid Control?

Tags: wpf, uniformgrid

`UnifomGrid` has loaded Data, I want to Hide the first row?

How can I implement that?

Answer (score 1):

I've never worked with the `UniformGrid` so there might be a better solution for this but as far as I can tell the `UniformGrid` doesn't hold much information except how many rows and columns it currently have so therefore this is the only solution that I can think of.

```
private List<UIElement> GetElementsAtRow(int rowNumber)
{
    List<UIElement> elementsAtRow = new List<UIElement>();
    for (int i = 0; i < uniformGrid.Columns; i++)
    {
        if (i < uniformGrid.Children.Count)
        {
            elementsAtRow.Add(uniformGrid.Children[i] as UIElement);
        }
    }
    return elementsAtRow;
}
private void HideFirstRow()
{
    List<UIElement> elementsAtRow = GetElementsAtRow(0);
    foreach (UIElement element in elementsAtRow)
    {
        // Or Hidden if you want row to remain but with no Visible children.
        element.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    }
}
private void ShowFirstRow()
{
    List<UIElement> elementsAtRow = GetElementsAtRow(0);
    foreach (UIElement element in elementsAtRow)
    {
        element.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much,I am appreciate for you.